# In Swift, is there a way to go to one of several views when a button is pressed based on where the user came from?

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

One of my views is a `SearchViewController` and there is a cancel button at the top left. On the home screen of my app, there is a button that can be pressed that will take the user to this `SearchViewController`, and when this is done, the cancel button unwinds back to the `HomeViewController`.

There is another screen on my app which asks the user if they want to go to the `SearchViewController` if they are in a city that doesn't match one in our backend. If they decided yes, the app then loads the `SearchViewController`.

My question is, is there a way to make the cancel button in the top left unwind to a different view based on the `PresentingViewcontroller` or `ParentViewController`?

I've done a lot of Googling for this one under a couple different search strings and haven't found anything like what I'm asking, so I apologize if this question has been asked, maybe I just couldn't find the right words to describe my question.

**Update 1: Code and Screenshots**
[image: <code>SearchViewController</code>]
[image: <code>HomeViewController</code>]

And here is the unwind function in the `HomeViewController` that unwinds back to it.

`@IBAction func segueToHome (segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {}`

What I want to be able to achieve is to be able to use the cancel button to go back to where the user came from, which can be different, as another possible point of entry is here:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: You can add a custom back button to your nav bar then attach it to an action. What specifically did you mean by "different view based on the PresentingViewcontroller or ParentViewController"? Did you just want to go two view controllers back into the stack?

Comment: No. Sorry I was trying to be as clear as possible. I want the same cancel button to unwind to the view controller that presented it. Currently it will unwind but only to the HomeViewController and the SearchViewController has two different ways of being navigated to.

Comment: Could you post the code you're using for this "cancel" button and it's associated method?

Comment: Each of your presenting view controllers could set a property in your searchcontroller. Then your cancel button's IBAction method could test this property and call one of two different performSegueWithIdentifier methods to go back to the correct view controller. As Lyndsey said, this would probably require a custom back button so you can add your own IBAction to it to replace the default behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, ignore my comment above. Just woke up and not thinking straight.